# Работа со свежесозданными DIV в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

В html через `$.get( 'read.php' )` получаю тексты для div, создаю их через `append`, 
затем идет проверка - если текст с ошибкой, то div красится красным.
Такая же проверка при изменениях (`div`'ы `contenteditable`)
Работает через раз :(
Подозреваю, что нужно событие, когда дивы уже точно создались.

Код:

```
// Загрузка данных из php
$(function() {
  $.get("read.php", function(data) {
    var ionka = data.split(' ');
    ionka.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
      var app_text = "<div id=\"segm" + i + "\" contenteditable role=\"textbox\">" + item + "</div>";
      $("#textarea").append(app_text);
    });
  });
});
// Проверки после загрузки
$.get("read.php").done(function(data) {
  var intRegex = new RegExp('^[0-9/\]{5}$'); // 5 symbols, numbers and forward slashes  
  // Проверки сразу после загрузки
  $('#textarea div').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (i > 1) { // для первого элемента проверка не нужна
      if (!intRegex.test($(this).text())) {
        $(this).addClass("fill_red");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass();
      }
    }
  });
  // Проверки после изменения текста (для contenteditable корректно только через blur получилось
  var segm_array = [];
  $('#textarea div').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(this).blur(function() {
      if (segm_array[i] != $(this).text()) {
        segm_array[i] = $(this).text();
        if (!intRegex.test(segm_array[i])) {
          $(this).addClass("fill_red");
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML вот такой =D

```
<div id="textarea"></div>
```

Comment: одно не могу понять, зачем два раза запрашивать данные с сервера, а не поместить все в один `callback` ( `promise` )? у вас же два раза данные запрашиваются с сервера

Comment: Знаю что 2 раза, но с jQuery / js опыта почти нет, пока этот вариант самый рабочий:( Сейчас почитаю про callback.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вам хватит и одного вызова, один из параметров `$.get` - `callback` - вы его используете для создания блоков. Почему бы туда не вынести и ваши ф-ции проверки?

```
// Загрузка данных из php
$(function() {
    $.get("read.php", function(data) {
      var ionka = data.split(' ');
      ionka.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        var app_text = "<div id=\"segm" + i + "\" contenteditable role=\"textbox\">" + item + "</div>";
        $("#textarea").append(app_text);
      });
      var intRegex = new RegExp('^[0-9/\]{5}$'); // 5 symbols, numbers and forward slashes 
      var segm_array = [];
      // Один цикл вместо двух, один запрос вместо двух
      $('#textarea div').each(function(i, elem) {
        if (i > 1) { // для первого элемента проверка не нужна
          if (!intRegex.test($(this).text())) {
            $(this).addClass("fill_red");
          } else {
            $(this).removeClass();
          }
        }
        $(this).blur(function() {
          if (segm_array[i] != $(this).text()) {
            segm_array[i] = $(this).text();
            if (!intRegex.test(segm_array[i])) {
              $(this).addClass("fill_red");
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass();
            }
          }
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Пока не очень понимаю почему, но все работает, спасибо!

Comment: А как можно перезапустить `$(function() { .. });` без обновления страницы? По кнопке "Загрузить новые тексты" текст текущих дивов будет сохраняться, и read.php будет выдавать уже новую порцию. Т.е. по этой кнопке надо удалить старые DIV и выполнить 1 в 1 тот же код.

Comment: вывел код `$(function() { .. });` в отдельную функцию и просто перезапускаю его когда нужно.